# How can I handle a duplicate durable Stomp subscriber?

Tags: activemq-classic, stomp, durable-subscription

I have multiple Ruby processes that start up and try to connect to a topic via a durable subscriber using Stomp.

The first process succeeds, and reads messages (yay).

Subsequent processes fail, and repeatedly try to reconnect.

How can my processes **discover that the durable subscriber is already connected**, and quit trying to connect?

Possible imaginary code snippet:

```
begin
  stomp_client.subscribe()
rescue ClientAlreadySubscribedException
  puts "No problem, let's keep doing our other code"
end
```

### Environment:

- Ruby 1.9.3
- stompgem 1.3.2

### Code:

```
require 'stomp'

# Connect with durable subscription
hash = {
  hosts: [
    { host: "localhost", port: 61613, ssl: false }
  ],
  connect_headers: {
    :"client-id" => "durableRubyTest"
  }
}
stomp_client = Stomp::Client.new( hash )

stomp_client.subscribe "/topic/durable.test.dev",
    {"activemq.subscriptionName" => "devtest" } do |msg|
  puts "Message! "
  puts msg.inspect
end
puts "Connected to stomp, waiting for messages..."
stomp_client.join
```

Comment: Instead of `Stomp::Client` you can use `Stomp::Connection` which gives you error messages. 
To avoid "repeatedly try to reconnect" issue, You can use `max_reconnect_attempts` option in config_hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicate durable subscribers should receive an ERROR frame that indicates the problem.  If you receive an ERROR frame after the subscribe you can handle the problem there.

Comment: Stomp-wise, yes. However, a change to the Stomp Gem may be required in order to handle this. In the context of this question, it's not quite the answer I was going for.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a bug tracker.  If you need changes to STOMP gem then use their bug reporting tool.

Comment: Using feature request - https://github.com/stompgem/stomp/issues/101 to track this.